# typescript. array returning type of argument

Tags: typescript, return-type

```
function last(anArray:any[]) /*:????*/ {
    return anArray[anArray.length-1];
}
```

Without resorting to generics, is it possible to specify the return type in the function above being the type of the elements of the argument so

```
let strs:string[]=["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
let lastStr=last(strs);     // type of lastStr should be string

let dates:Date[]=[new Date];
let lastDate=last(dates);      // type of lastDate should be Date
```

**Edit**: Seeing the fine answer from @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir I should have stated "Without resorting to generics when invoking the function"

Comment: It's not possible without generics. Why don't you want to use a generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you say 'without resorting to generics'. This is exactly the reason for generics in typescript. Using generics is not that hard:

```
function last<T>(anArray:T[]) :T {
    return anArray[anArray.length-1];
}
// usage

let strs:string[]=["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
let lastStr=last(strs);     // string

let dates:Date[]=[new Date()];
let lastDate=last(dates); //date
```

Without generics there is no way to accomplish this.

Comment: It's not about ease of use. While I agree with your statement, he wants a solution without generics (if it even exists), not one with generics.

Comment: @Lansana Added a line in the answer stating clearly that without generics this is not posible

Comment: Well, I was after some straight code, I feel a bit redundant having to specify the type when invoking a simple function like this, just wondering if it would be possible...

Comment: @Joan, but that is the beauty of generics, you don't have to specify the type, TS infers it. Added usage

Comment: Ahhh! I was assuming you should state the type when invoking it!. Sorry for the ambiguity of "without resorting to generics" that caused a bit of a misunderstood but you got the essence of the question. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid the generics, but you don't have to specify them as they can be inferred automatically. The accepted answer is probably good enough for your needs, but there is another way...

Typescript 2.8 will introduce type inferring (its currently published as a nightly build). With it you can support (fixed-size N) tuples of arbitrary types, rather than all elements being the same type, by combining conditional-types with type-inference.

```
type tuple =
  [any] |
  [any, any] |
  [any, any, any] |
  [any, any, any, any];

type TupleLast<T extends tuple> =
  T extends [infer L] ? L :
  T extends [any, infer L] ? L : 
  T extends [any, any, infer L] ? L : 
  T extends [any, any, any, infer L] ? L : any;

function last<T extends tuple>(arg: T): TupleLast<T> {
  return arg[arg.length - 1];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Consider this answer a mental exercise of what can be done - I'm still messing with the new toys. :D

Comment: I have only 2 weeks of typescriping and I am a bit overwhelmed with its beauty errmmm and my mental abilities to catch up with all the possibilities :-) (but I repeat myself take it easy it's a matter of time)